# PivotTable.js - sum aggregator does not show zeros

Tags: javascript, pivot-table, pivottable.js

I am using PivotTable.js to pivot some data for a report. In the report, I have a need to show rows for which the aggregate sum is zero, and would like to display that zero in the totals column. When using the aggregatorTemplates.sum, the aggregate sum of zeros seems to be a black cell. I wonder if there is a way to render the zero?

A simplified example of what I'm doing is

```
var sum = $.pivotUtilities.aggregatorTemplates.sum;
var numberFormat = $.pivotUtilities.numberFormat;
var intFormat = numberFormat({digitsAfterDecimal: 0});

$("#output").pivot(
  [
    {color: "green", shape: "null", value: 0},
    {color: "blue", shape: "circle", value: 1},
    {color: "red", shape: "triangle", value: 2},
    {color: "blue", shape: "circle", value: 3},
    {color: "red", shape: "triangle", value: 4}
  ],
  {
    rows: ["color"],
    cols: ["shape"],
    aggregator: sum(intFormat)(["value"])
  }
);
```

This is the example from https://pivottable.js.org/examples/simple_agg.html, modified to illustrate the issue I'm facing. This is also available in a fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/rgs258/dky0hh1y/.

As a secondary question, I wonder if there's a way to hide the 'null' column in my example?

Any help or advice in resolving this is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(I'm the library author :)

You can override the built-in number formatting (which is hiding the zeros) by creating a locale file: https://github.com/nicolaskruchten/pivottable/wiki/Localization

You can hide the null columns using the `filter` or `exclusions` parameters: https://github.com/nicolaskruchten/pivottable/wiki/Parameters

Comment: Sorry, but your documentation about locale files states nothing about not hiding the zeros.  Can you please provide an example of a pivot table that shows all cells, regardless of the value?

Comment: If you could update this fiddle, that would be awesome. https://jsfiddle.net/dky0hh1y/1/

Comment: The localization documentation shows how you can override number formatting to be whatever you like it to be. I should also note that the default behaviour has changed since this answer was posted, and zeros are now shown for all cells with data. Cells without data never show anything and there is no way to force them to.

Comment: Funny, I just discovered your update (https://pivottable.js.org/dist/pivot.js).  So, no need to do anything.  From what I read in your documentation, we can certainly develop localization to format numbers according to how we need it, but saw nothing about hiding or showing zeros.  But that a moot point now.  Thanks for the awesome pivot table.